# Pymongo/monodb использует много памяти и постепенно замедляется

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

При использовании функции, в основе которой лежит `db.collection.find({})`, в цикле наблюдаю, что он начинает замедлятся, а процесс **mongodb** использует все больше памяти. Пример:

```
def find_person(data):
    host='***'
    table_name='***'
    mng_client = pymongo.MongoClient(host, 27017)
    mng_db = mng_client['local']
    db_cm = mng_db[table_name]
    df= pd.DataFrame()
    for i in ["", "_rus"]:
        d = db_cm.find({
                        'first_name': proccess_name(data['firstname'+i]),
                        'last_name': proccess_name(data['lastname'+i]),
                         },
                       {'_id':0,'id':1})
        df=df.append(pd.DataFrame(list(d)))
    mng_client.close()
    return df

for i in range(0, len(client_data)):
    find_person(client_data.iloc[i])
```

Прошу помочь решить проблему.

Comment: пробовали заниматься дебаггингом, хотя бы просто с помощью `pdb` или [чем-нибудь другим](https://habrahabr.ru/company/mailru/blog/205426/)?

Comment: Нет, мне кажется что это на стороне монги. Что то типа кеширования.

Comment: вы на каждом шаге цикла создаете нового клиента, попробуйте создать его отдельно и передавать аргументом в find_person

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте использовать мап редюс Пример для вашего случая

```
mapper = """
function map() {
    if((this.last_name '%s' & this.first_name == '%s') | (this.last_name == '%s_rus' & this.first_name == '%s_rus')){
        emit(this._id,{'some_return_var':this.some_var, ...});
    }
}
"""
reducer = """
                function reduce(key, values) {
                }
          """
result_set = self.mongo[self.collection_name].map_reduce(mapper, reducer, out='Названия промежуточной колекции куда он будет ложить найденые данные')
```

После в result_set.find( вы получаете лист словарей по типу `{'_id': 'UUID внутрених документов в колекциях', 'values': 'значения которые вы указали для возврата в маппере.'}`

В моем случае выборка по тайм стампу в колекции с 150к документов происходит за "буквально в щелчек пальцев"

Есть проблема что в разных потоках вызов мап-редюса будет ложить в одну промежуточную колекцию утраняется это , и вызвать наложение документов

```
 def _map_reduce(self, mapper, reducer):
        self.result_collection = uuid.uuid4().__str__()
        result_set = self.mongo[self.collection_name].map_reduce(mapper, reducer, out=SON(
            [("replace", self.result_collection), ("db", MONGODB_NAME)]))
        l = list()
        for doc in result_set.find():
            l.append(doc)
        self.mongo[self.result_collection].drop()
        return l
```